# Equivalence of Markov chain definitions

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I'm studying markovianity of quantum process and the two article that i'm reading right now refers to two different definition of classical markovianity.
The first one is the definition reported also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Markov_chain), and it is also what I studied in class.
The second one is essentially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality). Both the article and Wikipedia refer to the same book, but there is no the proof of equivalence of the two definition.

My question is: how can I prove that are equivalent?
It seems reasonable to me that 1 implies 2, but I have no idea how to prove.
Implication 2 $\implies$ 1, I am not even sure is true.

Comment: "Second definition" if stated so (that is without information at which step we are already) will work only for homogenous discrete time markov chains.

Comment: You are right! I think that is not a big problem since in most of the article I read only 3 step discrete processes are considered. So my question can be restated as "are these definition equivalent restricting the analysis to only 3 steps? If so, How can you prove it?"

Comment: I mean, it isn't that important how many steps we took, but it is rather important whether the probabilities changes when we're in different steps. You can google time-homogenous Markow Chains. It is a Markov Chain with assumption like $\mathbb P(X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i) = \mathbb P(X_1 = j | X_0 = i)$ (that is it doesn't matter whether at $n'$th step or at first step). If you're assuming your markow chain is homogenous you can prove the equivalence of definitions. If you're not assuming it, you must change (not much) second definition

Comment: Now I think I have understood. How do you prove equivalence if the chain it is homogenous? Because I can imagine that there exists a process where the second definition is respected, but if we condition two intermediate step instead of one, there isn't  independence. I thought that such a process is not Markovian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I will prove general fact about Markow Chains and then I'll go to your definitions for the case of homogenous one.

Let $(X_n)$ be a discrete time process. I'll use the following notation:

1. $\mu$ will be the distribution of $X_0$ that is $\mu(a):= \mu(\{a\}) = \mathbb P(X_0=a)$.
2. $A_n(a,b) = \mathbb P( X_n = b | X_{n-1}=a)$ if $\mathbb P(X_{n-1}=a) > 0$ (that is $A_n$ can be interpreted as a matrix with entries - probabilities of certain direction in $n'$th step).

Now our definitions are:

(1) $(X_n)$ is a Markow Chain if $\mathbb P(X_{n+1} = a_{n+1} | X_n = a_n , ... ,X_0 = a_0) = \mathbb P(X_{n+1} = a_{n+1} | X_n = a_n)$ for any $a_0,...,a_{n+1}$ such that it makes sense ( $\mathbb P(X_n = a_n ,... , X_0 = a_0) > 0 $)

(2) $(X_n)$ is a Markow Chain if $\mathbb P(X_0=a_0,...,X_n = a_n) = \mu(a_0)A_1(a_0,a_1)A_2(a_1,a_2)...A_n(a_{n-1},a_n)$ for any $a_0,...,a_n$ such that it makes sense.

Proof:

Direction (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2)

We're work with induction. Note that $\mathbb P(X_0 = a_0) = \mu(a_0)$ by definition of $\mu$, so the induction basis holds. Assume it holds for $n-1$. Then for $n$ we get:

$$ \mathbb P(X_0=a_0,...,X_n=a_n) = \mathbb P(X_{n} = a_{n} | X_{n-1}=a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0) \mathbb P(X_{n-1} = a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0)$$

where we used definition $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A | B) \mathbb P(B)$. Now for the first term on the right apply definition (1) and for the second term apply induction step, to get:

$$ \mathbb P(X_0=a_0,...,X_n=a_n) = \mathbb P(X_n =a_n | X_{n-1}=a_{n-1})\mathbb P(X_{n-1}=a_{n-1} | X_{n-2} = a_{n-2})... \mathbb P(X_0=a_0)$$ what can be rewritten as $$ \mathbb P(X_0=a_0,...,X_n=a_n) = \mu(a_0)A_1(a_0,a_1)...A_n(a_{n-1},a_n)$$

Direction (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1)

Simplier, just definition of conditional probability (conditioned on event with prob. greater than $0$)

$$ \mathbb P(X_n=a_n | X_{n-1}=a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0) = \frac{\mathbb P(X_n=a_n,...,X_0=a_0)}{\mathbb P(X_{n-1}=a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0)}$$ And now use (2) for numerator and denominator to get $$ \mathbb P(X_n=a_n| X_{n-1}=a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0) = A_n(a_{n-1},a_n) = \mathbb P(X_n = a_n | X_{n-1}=a_{n-1})$$

Homogenous case:

Note that in this case, we just have $A_n(a,b)$ is the same for every $n$, so we can just define $p(b|a) = A_1(a,b) = \mathbb P(X_1 = b | X_0=a)$ and $p(a) = \mathbb P(X_0=a)$ (that is we don't need to care about time when we want to go to different states, only about the states from which and where we go to).

Definition $1$ may be unchanged (or $\mathbb P(X_n = a_n | X_{n-1}=a_{n-1},...,X_0=a_0) = \mathbb P(X_1 = a_n | X_0=a_{n-1})$

Definition $2$ changes to $\mathbb P(X_n=a_n,...,X_0=a_0) = p(a_0)p(a_1|a_0)...p(a_n|a_{n-1})$ which is exactly the notation used in your definition.

Comment: Consider a generic stochastic process and define $C(n,k; y_1, ...,y_k) =  \sum_{y_{n-1},  y_{n+1}}\mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=y_{n-1}|X_n=y_1,...,X_{n+k-1}=y_k)  \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|X_n=y_1,...,X_{n+k-1}=y_k) -  \mathbb{P}(X_{n-1}=y_{n-1},X_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|X_n=y_1,...,X_{n+k-1}=y_k)$. Is it true that if this quantity is 0 for all choice of $n,k$ and $y_1, ...,y_k$ then the process is Markov? An article I'm reading seems to claim this, but I'm not convinced.